# Entity Framework - DB first foreign key table won't show as model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, edmx

I have created a table with two primary keys and two foreign keys, both foreign keys refer to the same column in the base table - script as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef](
    [PitzulHafrashotIdShlili] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PitzulHafrashotIdShotef] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TaarichIdkun] [datetime2](7) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PitzulHafrashotIdShlili] ASC,
    [PitzulHafrashotIdShotef] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef_TG_PitzulHafrashot] FOREIGN KEY([PitzulHafrashotIdShlili])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TG_PitzulHafrashot] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef_TG_PitzulHafrashot]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef_TG_PitzulHafrashot1] FOREIGN KEY([PitzulHafrashotIdShotef])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TG_PitzulHafrashot] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef_TG_PitzulHafrashot1]
GO
```

I have then went to my code and updated my model from the DB, added the new table and expected to see a new generated model of the new table.

However, the new model did not generate and my base model looked like that:

```
  public partial class TG_PitzulHafrashot
    {
        public TG_PitzulHafrashot()
        {
            this.TG_PitzulHafrashot1 = new HashSet<TG_PitzulHafrashot>();
            this.TG_PitzulHafrashot2 = new HashSet<TG_PitzulHafrashot>();
        }
        /* unrelated properties 
        */
        public virtual ICollection<TG_PitzulHafrashot> TG_PitzulHafrashot1 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TG_PitzulHafrashot> TG_PitzulHafrashot2{ get; set; }
    }
```

I then deleted the FK constraint from the new table and updated the model again. 
After I updated the model. Now, the new class was generated as expected, with no constraints on the base model:

```
public partial class TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef
{
    public int PitzulHafrashotIdShlili { get; set; }
    public int PitzulHafrashotIdShotef { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TaarichIdkun { get; set; }

    public virtual TG_PitzulHafrashot TG_PitzulHafrashot { get; set; }
    public virtual TG_PitzulHafrashot TG_PitzulHafrashot1 { get; set; }
}
```

I then added the FK constraint to the new table and updated the model yet again - The relation created just fine now:

```
   public TG_PitzulHafrashot()
    {
        this.TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef = new HashSet<TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef>();
        this.TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef1 = new HashSet<TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef>();
    }

    /* unrelated properties
    */        

    public virtual ICollection<TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef> TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef> TG_PitzulHafrashotShliliVsShotef1 { get; set; }
}
```

My question is, does entity framework not no how to generate model with and foreign keys properly?

this was a very weird situation as the new table was added to the `SqlServer.edmx` file however, was not shown in the designer and the corresponding models were never generated, only after I created a table without constraints.

Is there any solution for the foreign key constraint in EF db first?